# Mvvm pattern for windows phone app using StatusBar and MessageDialog

Tags: unit-testing, mvvm, statusbar

I have a windows phone app that uses the mvvm pattern. Current I am controlling the status bar and showing message dialogs from the ViewModel. So far I have 2 possible solutions:

1. make interfaces for the StatusBar and MessageDialog inject the instance:

   ```
   public interface IMessageDialog
   {
       Task ShowMessage(string message);
   }

   public class MessageDialog: IMessageDialog
   {
       async Task ShowMessage(string message)
       {
           await new MessageDialog(message).ShowAsync();
       }
   }

   //In the view model locator
   SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IMessageDialog, MessageDialog>();
   ```
2. use a messenger and have the view handle it

   ```
   Messenger.Default.Send<string>(Constants.ConnectionErrorDialog, Constants.UIMessages);
   ```

Please note that I am also using the ResourceLoader to get localized strings and I want to be able to unit test my app.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean with "make interfaces and inject the instance"? Do you mean injecting StatusBar/MessageDialog controls into your ViewModel? I wouldn't advise this as it breaks the MVVM pattern. Could you post some code/XAML so people get a better picture of what you have now and what to improve with it

Comment: I posted some examples

Answer (score 0):

The general way of doing it, is via Dialog or Navigation Service (later one for Views/Windows/Pages obviously), which brings it to Option 1 for Dialogs

I am not familiar with the StatusBar thing, but if it can be declared in XAML, you can create and bind a ViewModel and then use an event aggregation (Messaging). Your StatusViewModel would bind its properties and register to the event aggregator, while your other ViewModel will send the events.

I wouldn't implement the event/message handling in the View's code behind, as this is isn't View logic and belongs to the ViewModel. Always use event aggregator/messaging to communicate between ViewModels, never for Views.